# Different output from same code with exponents in python

Tags: python, loops, numpy, exponential

I'm running some code in a loop, which runs for many thousands of data points, where at one point I have this line of code:

```
z[i, j] = -math.exp(oneminusbeta[j, i])
```

I put comments **before** each line of code, and the last line comment outputted before the code crashed was this:

```
z[30416,20] = -math.exp(oneminusbeta (which is 8.04812689598e-13))
```

The error was:

```
OverflowError: math range error
```

Which means that the above line caused the crash. 
However, when I open a separate console and type this

```
a = -math.exp(8.04812689598e-13)
print str(a)
```

My code doesn't crash. It just outputs:

```
-1.0
```

What's going on? Why is it that in the middle of a bunch of code, raising an exponent to this power makes the program crash, but it doesn't crash otherwise? What can I do to prevent this? Or how do I know when python will decide some exponent is too much to deal with and suddenly crash?

### Edit

Similar to the way I initialized z, I just tried this:

```
a = np.empty([1,1]) 
a[0,0] = -math.exp(8.04812689598e-13) 
print str(a)
```

But this doesn't crash either.

### Edit 2

Someone suggested that the error might be caused by the line after the comment output.
The line after the one I mentioned looks like this:

```
weights[i,j] = math.exp(beta[j,i] + oneminusbeta[j,i])
```

### Edit 3

I ran the code again and whilst in the above example, the code crashed on `weights[30816, 42]`, this time it crashed on `weights[55399, 43]`. Which means that this time it didn't overflow on the same spot it overflowed above, but in another spot. Which means that it isn't really an issue of python not being able to do the calculation.

But I'm using exactly the same dataset as before.
What's going on and is there any solution to this arbitrary issue? I'm using Anaconda Spyder on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: What type of object is `z` ? Could it be that `z` is `float32` container, while a is a 64bit float?

Comment: how can I find out? This is how I initialized z: `z = np.empty([n,m])` and I'm using numpy versions 1.8.2.

Comment: I just tried this: `a = np.empty([1,1])     a[0,0] = -math.exp(8.04812689598e-13)    print str(a)` but it doesn't crash either.

Comment: You'd get an overflow if `oneminusbeta` was 8.04812689598e13. Are you sure about its value?

Comment: ok if you did not explicitly tell numpy to create a float32, it is not a float32 then.

Comment: did you double check the value of  `oneminusbeta`? As @khelwood mentions, e+13 is more plausible than e-13 for such exception

Comment: FWIW, exp(8.04812689598e-13) ~= 1.00000000000080481268959832386, and exp(8.04812689598e13) ~= 4.0192352016871412017421425E+34952571005812, calculated using mpmath.

Comment: Are you able to post your code as an [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: What is next value of oneminusbeta[j, i]? Some implementation of Python system, execution of code and I/O of keyboard/screen are performed concurrently by multiple threads. If error message has higher priority than usual output, and "math range error" occurred when output message of next data is prepared but not displayed yet, You see error massage after the message of privious data.

Comment: I see, so you're saying that the crash might actually be based on the next line of code, and not this line? I'm just editing the question to include my next line of code.

Comment: I ran it again and it's actually cruising through the issue it crashed on earlier, and now crashing at a new place. I've edited my question.

Comment: What happens if you change math.exp to np.exp?

Comment: I just ran it using np.exp instead. Same issue, this time the last message output was from weights[30816, 42] again.